# What is the world of Faerûn like after the events of Rise of Tiamat?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, forgotten-realms, lore, rise-of-tiamat

Are there any references for what the world of Faerûn is like after the events of *Rise of Tiamat*, assuming a band of characters successfully stopped the return of Tiamat to Faerûn?

What facts are known about the end of *Rise of Tiamat* that might suggest what the world would be like?

Answer (score 8):

Page 88 of the *Rise of Tiamat* adventure (which I won't reproduce here because copyright and spoilers) briefly summarizes the aftermath of both possible outcomes: defeat, or victory. Beyond what is described there, nothing else has been officially stated, AFAIK.

Answer (score 7):

## The Rise of Tiamat book provides a brief description

On page 88 of *Rise of Tiamat*, brief epilogue passages are provided for both defeat and victory. The "victory" epilogue provides some guidance in this regard, but is relatively general in its description, speaking at the level of the whole Sword Coast rather than anything specific to particular cities.

## Beyond that, the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide

The *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* is dated after *RoT* due to a specific detail it provides about a city's leadership (tagged for *RoT* spoilers):

> The *SCAG* notes Laeral Silverhand as the Open Lord of Waterdeep, having ousted Dagult Neverember. This is an event that takes place within the *Rise of Tiamat* campaign...

and thus the *SCAG* must detail the state of the world after *Rise of Tiamat*. As such, the *SCAG* can be used as a reference for the state of Faerun post *Rise of Tiamat* - although it draws few (if any) explicit links between the events of *RoT* and the state of the world.

Comment: After - or possibly during?